# Ticket System in Java but NullPointerException in main when creating members

Tags: java, oop, nullpointerexception

I'm writing program that works in ticket offices. there are two classes , passenger and Reservation. But when i creating passenger class , the 'if' part of code is not working and gives errror that nullpointerexception. 'else' part is working. Here is the output and error:

```
run:
Choose option for processing; 
1. Add a new passenger
2. Add a reservation for an existing Passenger 
3. Display reservations
4. Cancel reservation
0. Quit
1
enter a name :
gokhan
adress : 
nas
Number :
212
password : 
123456
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at project1.testClass.main(testClass.java:47)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 7 seconds)   // what a succesful.
```

message says error in this line;

```
  System.out.println("password : ");
  password=input.nextLine();
    if(password.equals("ffffff")){
  System.out.println("Password should be six characters!\nYour password is: "+password);
    break ;
     }
     else { 
  passenger[count]= new Passenger(name,adress,number,password);   //  this line 
  count++;
  passenger[count].getAccID();
  System.out.println("Password should be six characters!\nYour password is: "+password);
    break ;
     }
```

so this is passenger class:

```
 public Passenger(String Name, String adress, String number, String password){

count++;
accID+=count;
AccountList[count]=accID;


this.Name=Name;

this.adress=adress;
this.number=number;

if(checkPw(password)==true){
this.password=password;
}
else { 
    this.password="ffffff";
}

private boolean checkPw(String password){

int length;
length = password.length();

if (length != 6) {
    return false;
    }
if (password.charAt(0)=='0'){
   return false;
}
else {
    for (int i = 0; i < password.length()-1 ;i++){
    if((password.charAt(i))==(password.charAt(i+1))){
        return false;
    }
    }
}
return true;

}
```

Comment: Usually when checking strings against literal strings, I change the order to prevent any NPE; v.g. `if ("ffffff".equals(password))`. That does not explain why `password` is null at that line, though.

Comment: It would suggest that the password array is null

Comment: stupid question, are you initialize `passenger[]`?

Comment: How have you defined `input`? I find strange that you are not using `System.in`

Comment: at first i don't ffffff when it 'else'. when it else , it's doing automatically null. but it didn't work too. so, what can i do for resolve this?

Comment: what a stupid questions. OF COURSE i intialize passenger[].
AND O COURSE i defined a input. I DIDN'T WRITE ALL CODE :S

Comment: these all codes working when just creating passenger so feel free. It does not work when i get inputs.

Comment: @GökhanNas if you're going to insult those who are trying to help you, then StackOverflow is the wrong place for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You think you initialized `passenger`, but actually you didn't. That's the only possible thing that could cause a NPE on that line.

Comment: private static Passenger[] passenger; ?

Comment: I guess you are another programmer who thinks that creates an object. It doesn't! You have to use `new`, in Java, to create an object.

Comment: @GökhanNas declaring and initializing is not the same thing

Comment: and +1 for the answer btw

Comment: thanks Robin. Sorry, my langauge that learning java is not english so i don't know some terms. Thanks!